# PingFederate SP SLO not going to IDP

Tags: pingfederate

We are using PingFederate as an SP and have configured opentokenadapter. We are also using PingFederate Apache Agent (mod_pf.so) for SSO. When the user is clicking on logout link below steps are happening:

1. Call goes to the logout url defined in mod_pf.conf file (PingFederateCancelURL) This is our application logout page.
2. Another call goes to /sp/startSLO.png and I can see SLO logs in the pingfederate server.

However there is no call going to IDP configured for this connection. Are we missing any configuration?

P.S. We have not configured **Logout Service** in the opentoken adapter configuration.

Adding Logs:

```
2016-06-13 03:01:36,128 tid:C0aV2SqcQXoy97ployGFLFGFR14 DEBUG [org.sourceid.websso.servlet.IntegrationControllerServlet] GET: https://ny-pingfed-app02.na.rtdom.net:9031/sp/startSLO.ping
2016-06-13 03:01:36,128 tid:C0aV2SqcQXoy97ployGFLFGFR14 DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.grouprpc.PreferredNodes] [] -> indices to addresses -> [10.221.56.36:7600, 10.221.56.29:7600]
2016-06-13 03:01:36,128  DEBUG [com.pingidentity.jgroups.MuxInvocationHandler] invocation of lookupAuthnBeansAndSessions on org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.SpSessionRegistryMapImpl@7a85063c{bean->session=19, nidKey->sessionlists=7, pfsessionid->beanslist=17} w/args: [oYxtMFSy5GYQ5lK3EN1Lkt] returned {SpHashableAuthnBean: 8b3ec7801a2976aa103df829dffc21f260ea7aca=WebSsoSession{entityId='https://devci-casshib-ny.mediaocean.com/idp/shibboleth', assertionId='_36dab27f092d6367407cb9042e350aed', sessionIndex='_0d66d53a8fea5733ea5621a7b90b923b', nameId(value)=_3aa309b361c657bf1bc2a307d19ac432}}
2016-06-13 03:01:36,131 tid:C0aV2SqcQXoy97ployGFLFGFR14 DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.grouprpc.SpSessionRegistryGroupRpcImpl] called mode:GET_MAJORITY lookupAuthnBeansAndSessions([oYxtMFSy5GYQ5lK3EN1Lkt]) on [10.221.56.36:7600, 10.221.56.29:7600] responses:
[sender=10.221.56.36:7600, retval={SpHashableAuthnBean: 8b3ec7801a2976aa103df829dffc21f260ea7aca=WebSsoSession{entityId='https://devci-casshib-ny.mediaocean.com/idp/shibboleth', assertionId='_36dab27f092d6367407cb9042e350aed', sessionIndex='_0d66d53a8fea5733ea5621a7b90b923b', nameId(value)=_3aa309b361c657bf1bc2a307d19ac432}}, received=true, suspected=false]
[sender=10.221.56.29:7600, retval={SpHashableAuthnBean: 8b3ec7801a2976aa103df829dffc21f260ea7aca=WebSsoSession{entityId='https://devci-casshib-ny.mediaocean.com/idp/shibboleth', assertionId='_36dab27f092d6367407cb9042e350aed', sessionIndex='_0d66d53a8fea5733ea5621a7b90b923b', nameId(value)=_3aa309b361c657bf1bc2a307d19ac432}}, received=true, suspected=false]

2016-06-13 03:01:36,131 tid:C0aV2SqcQXoy97ployGFLFGFR14 DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.grouprpc.PreferredNodes] [] -> indices to addresses -> [10.221.56.36:7600, 10.221.56.29:7600]
2016-06-13 03:01:36,131 tid:C0aV2SqcQXoy97ployGFLFGFR14 DEBUG [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.grouprpc.SpSessionRegistryGroupRpcImpl] called mode:GET_NONE unregisterSessionsReceived([[SpHashableAuthnBean: 8b3ec7801a2976aa103df829dffc21f260ea7aca]]) on [10.221.56.36:7600, 10.221.56.29:7600]
2016-06-13 03:01:36,230  DEBUG [com.pingidentity.jgroups.MuxInvocationHandler] invocation of unregisterSessionsReceived on org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.SpSessionRegistryMapImpl@7a85063c{bean->session=18, nidKey->sessionlists=6, pfsessionid->beanslist=16} w/args: [[SpHashableAuthnBean: 8b3ec7801a2976aa103df829dffc21f260ea7aca]] returned null
2016-06-13 03:01:36,263 tid:C0aV2SqcQXoy97ployGFLFGFR14 DEBUG [org.sourceid.util.log.internal.TrackingIdSupport] [cross-reference-message] PFSessionXRefID:_0d66d53a8fea5733ea5621a7b90b923b
2016-06-13 03:01:36,501  WARN  [org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler]
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.sourceid.websso.profiles.ProcessRuntimeException: org.sourceid.saml20.adapter.AuthnAdapterException: Logout functionality invoked, but no logout service is configured for this adapter.
        at org.sourceid.servlet.ServletExceptionSupport.throwServletException(ServletExceptionSupport.java:26)
        at org.sourceid.websso.servlet.IntegrationControllerServlet.process(IntegrationControllerServlet.java:88)
        at org.sourceid.websso.servlet.EnforcerServletBase.checkProcess(EnforcerServletBase.java:84)
```

It seems that Logout Service is mandatory parameter. What should be it's value? Should it be IDP's SLO endpoint or application's (which SP is protecting) logout url?

Comment: _"and I can see SLO logs in the pingfederate server."_ Could you update your question with a "sanitized" log snippet, please? The log will hold the answer as to why it's not redirecting to the IdP.

Comment: The /sp/startSLO.png was getting blocked earlier due to cross-origin issue. I have added latest logs now.

Comment: I have the same problem. PingFederate SLO is called, but IdP session remains alive, therefore logout is never done. We put a nice "Close your browser" message as workaround. Existing PF documentation will not help anyone